# Boolean Expression Elevator Between Two Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

This is my first post here, and I hope that my question is clear and formatted correctly...

I have two dictionaries. The first dictionary contains what I'm calling "Option Expressions" as keys and arbitrary items for values:

```
dict1 = {'((opt1 OR opt4 OR opt6) AND NOT opt7)': 'Yellow Roof', '((opt2 AND opt3) XOR opt5': 'Purple Scooter'}

print(dict1)

{'((opt1 OR opt4 OR opt6) AND NOT opt7)': 'Yellow Roof',
'((opt2 AND opt3) XOR opt5': 'Purple Scooter'}
```

The second dictionary contains the options from `dict1` as keys and whether or not they were "Accepted" or "Rejected" as values:

```
dict2 = {'opt1': 'Accepted', 'opt2': 'Rejected', 'opt3': 'Rejected','opt4': 'Accepted', 'opt5': 'Accepted', 'opt6': 'Rejected','opt7': 'Accepted'}

print(dict2)

{'opt1': 'Accepted',
 'opt2': 'Rejected',
 'opt3': 'Rejected',
 'opt4': 'Accepted',
 'opt5': 'Accepted',
 'opt6': 'Rejected',
 'opt7': 'Accepted'}
```

How would I go about evaluating the expressions from `dict1` as `True` or `False` to determine which items were selected based on whether opt's from `dict2` were accepted or rejected?

My initial thought was to replace the opt's in the expressions with 1 for accepted and 0 for rejected to have something like:

`((1 OR 1 OR 0) AND NOT 1)` Which would evaluate as `False`

and

`((0 AND 0) XOR 1)` Which would evaluate as `True`

I've been doing some research into pyparsing and think it would be useful here, though I am not entirely sure how best to utilize it.

**I am applying boolean logic:**

AND: True if and only if both sides are true

OR: True if either side is true

NOT/(AND NOT): Changes true to false and false to true

XOR: True if one side is true (but 
 *not* both)

Comment: Are `opt` values bool-normalized or can they have a different value than `Accepted` or `Rejected`?

Comment: @zwer they are! They are only accepted or rejected.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to use it" doesn't make a good question. Read the doc, it will tell you how to use it, or explain exactly what you have tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: And btw, I suspect you inverted the keys and values in `dict1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little bit of massaging the data you can turn it into valid Python and let the Python interpreter do your bidding:

```
# Mandatory warning here about using eval() - here be dragons!

dict1 = {"((opt1 OR opt4 OR opt6) AND NOT opt7)": "Yellow Roof",
         "((opt2 AND opt3) XOR opt5)": "Purple Scooter"}

dict2 = {"opt1": "Accepted",
         "opt2": "Rejected",
         "opt3": "Rejected",
         "opt4": "Accepted",
         "opt5": "Accepted",
         "opt6": "Rejected",
         "opt7": "Accepted"}

# lets first normalize the 'opt' codes to True/False
dict2_norm = {k: (True if v == "Accepted" else False) for k, v in dict2.items()}

# Now all we need to do is evaluate the expressions:
for expression, value in dict1.items():
    # Let's first normalize the expression to Python-digestible
    expression = expression.replace("XOR", "is not").replace("OR", "or")\
        .replace("AND", "and").replace("NOT", "not")
    if eval(expression, dict2_norm):
        print(value)

# prints: Purple Scooter
```

Comment: Thanks! this solution is much simpler than what I was trying to implement :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with.  It assumes you've already replaced the 'Accepted' and 'Rejected' with True and False (or 1 and 0 like you said in your question.)

This then will process the results.  It first formats the results into valid Python code ('xor' -> `^`, 'AND' -> `and`, and 'OR' -> `or`), replaces the opt values with their boolean counterparts, and finally evaluates the expression using the `eval` builtin.

```
input_code = '((opt1 OR opt4 OR opt6) AND NOT opt7)'
input_w_xor = '(opt2 AND opt3) XOR opt5'
result_codes = {'opt1': True, 'opt2': False, 'opt3': False,'opt4': True, 'opt5': True, 'opt6': False,'opt7': True}


def process_code(input_code, result_codes):
    input_code = input_code.lower()

    def replace_op_codes(code):
        for opt_key, opt_value in result_codes.items():
            code =  code.replace(opt_key, str(opt_value))
        return code

    input_code = replace_op_codes(input_code)
    input_code = input_code.replace("xor", '^')
    result = eval(input_code)

    return result


print(process_code(input_code, result_codes))
print(process_code(input_w_xor, result_codes))
```

I tend to shy away from using `eval` and `exec`, but I think it is the quickest solution in this case.